# Display the Names and Date of Births of all Programmers Born in January

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime-format

I am trying to use datetime to find the date of births (DOB) during January of certain PName. I have a short part that works in SQL Server, but I would like to find out the DOB of Jan or 1st month. It works in SQL Server for the whole database, but when I want to find just the particular month (DOB) of the database I can't find a correct way to right it. According to the Internet the Oracle it was written:

```
SELECT DOB, NAME FROM PROGRAMMER WHERE TO_CHAR(DOB,'MON') LIKE 'JAN';
```

I am trying to find the SQL Server - Programmer with DOB - say January

Name and dates of DOB with Jan

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [Programmer_Id]
  , [PName]
  **, [DOB]**
  , [DOB2]
  , [DOJ]
  , [DOJ2]
  , [Gender]
  , [Prof1]
  , [Prof2]
  , [Salary]
  , [Salary2]
FROM [Studies_S_P_no_foreign].[dbo].[Programmer]


SELECT 
   DATEPART(month, DOB) [month] --@d2  DOB  '2019-01-01 14:30:14'
   --where DOB is like 1
From Programmer

[Programmer_Id],[PName], [DOB], [DOB2], [DOJ], [DOJ2], [Gender], [Prof1],  [Prof2], [Salary], [Salary2]
1   ANAND   1966-04-12 00:00:00.000 1966-04-01  1992-04-21 00:00:00.000 1992-04-21  M   PASCAL  BASIC   3200    3200.00
2   ALTAF   1964-07-02 00:00:00.000 1964-07-02  1990-11-13 00:00:00.000 1990-11-13  M   CLIPPER COBOL   2800    2800.00
3   JULIANA 1960-01-31 00:00:00.000 1960-01-31  1990-04-21 00:00:00.000 1990-04-21  F   COBOL   DBASE   3000    3000.00
4   KAMALA  1968-10-30 00:00:00.000 1968-10-30  1992-01-02 00:00:00.000 1992-01-02  F   C   DBASE   2900    2900.00
5   MARY    1970-06-24 00:00:00.000 1970-06-24  1991-02-01 00:00:00.000 1991-02-01  F   CPP ORACLE  4500    4500.00
6   NELSON  1985-09-11 00:00:00.000 1985-09-11  1989-10-11 00:00:00.000 1989-10-11  M   COBOL   DBASE   2500    2500.00
7   PATTRICK    1965-11-10 00:00:00.000 1965-11-10  1990-04-21 00:00:00.000 1990-04-21  M   PASCAL  CLIPPER 2800    2800.00
8   QADIR   1965-08-31 00:00:00.000 1965-08-31  1991-04-21 00:00:00.000 1991-04-21  M   ASSEMBLY    C   3000    3000.00
9   RAMESH  1967-05-03 00:00:00.000 1967-05-03  1991-02-28 00:00:00.000 1991-02-28  M   PASCAL  DBASE   3200    3200.00
10  REBECCA 1967-01-01 00:00:00.000 1967-01-01  1990-12-01 00:00:00.000 1990-12-01  F   BASIC   COBOL   2500    2500.00
11  REMITHA 1970-04-19 00:00:00.000 1970-04-19  1993-04-20 00:00:00.000 1993-04-20  F   C   ASSEMBLY    3600    3600.00
12  REVATHI 1969-12-02 00:00:00.000 1969-12-02  1992-01-02 00:00:00.000 1992-01-02  F   PASCAL  BASIC   3700    3700.00
13  VIJAYA  1965-12-14 00:00:00.000 1965-12-14  1992-05-02 00:00:00.000 1992-05-02  F   FOXPRO  C   3500    3500.00
```

NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL

Comment: Please clarify, with sample data and desired results what you are trying to achieve. Based on your Oracle query you just want `where DATEPART(month, DOB) = 1`?

Comment: No I am not using Oracle. I am trying to use SQL Server. Unfortunately, the only Ex I found was Oracle. I am not very good at datetime() and other date functions. I am working with a name and then the dates within a 'Jan'. I need to look at the whole datebase.

Comment: I put the database in

Comment: Put your table definition to understand and try ourselves. Please provide minimum reproducible sample

Comment: I put the data in and the table definition. I am just stuck on getting Names, and particular month in DOB say January

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do the comparison in SQL Server. Below are some of them.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(DOB DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @table
values ('2019-01-01 14:30:14')

SELECT * FROM @table where MONTH(DOB) = 1
SELECT * FROM @table where DATENAME(mm,dob) = 'January'
SELECT * FROM @table where DATEPART(mm,dob) = 1
```

If want to do similar to Oracle for 3 character month

```sql
SELECT * FROM @table where LEFT(DATENAME(mm,dob),3) = 'JAN'
```

**CAVEAT** Thanks to @AlwaysLearning

> datename is set language-sensitive. e.g.: for January, French=janvier;
> Italian=gennaio; German=Januar; Spanish=Enero. If you have a
> multicultural database prefer to use month or datepart

Comment: Great answer but be aware that `datename` is `set language`-sensitive. e.g.: for January, French=`janvier`; Italian=`gennaio`; German=`Januar`; Spanish=`Enero`. If you have a multicultural database prefer to use `month` or `datepart`.

Comment: Yes, I can put in '2019-01-01 14:30:14' but I am looking at a small database and the DOB. I am trying to get the Jan or Feb or Mar or that database (DOB).                  Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 53
Must declare the table variable "@table".
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 56
Must declare the table variable "@table".
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 57
Must declare the table variable "@table".
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 58
Must declare the table variable "@table".

Comment: @Reed, I have just created table variable to show you, how to do it. You have apply similar where clause, in your table.

Comment: Yes, but that is where I am lost? I tried select * from Programmer where month(DOB) = 1 and I was getting Msg 1087

Comment: Yes, but that is where I am lost? I tried select * from Programmer where month(DOB) = 1 and I was getting Msg 1087     I am new to datetime function and a but rusty with Stack Over flow  - Sorry

Comment: @Reed we need a [mre] i.e. some sample data, the exact query you are using, and the full error you are receiving. Ideally as a dbfiddle. As it stands we can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select PNAME, DOB 
From Programmer
Where Month(DOB) = 01
```

Comment: This looks like the same answer venkataraman-r gave in 2021 except you put "01" instead of "1" (no difference as this is a numeric)